# How to get the count of the people have a better salary than the current tuple

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, window-functions

I was working on a problem from Leetcode [#185](https://leetcode.com/problems/department-top-three-salaries/)

I could understand the solution but I want to know how to write the query that add a column which indicate the count the people have a better salary than the tuple one. I think it is possible in SQL, but i don't know how to make it right, i always get syntax error. :-/

```
from Employee e1 (Select count(distinct e2.Salary)
                  from Employee e2
                  Where e2.Salary > e1.Salary) as c
```

For exemple I have such a table Employee:

```
Id - Name - Salary
1    toto   60000
2    tata   50000
3    kiki   90000
4    lily   70000
5    momo   60000
```

I want to have such a result:

```
Id - Name - Salary - Head_count_of_higher_salary
1    toto   60000      2
2    tata   50000      4
3    kiki   90000      0
4    lily   70000      1
5    momo   60000      2
```

Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subquery is almost correct.
Just remove `DISTINCT` from `COUNT()` (although just `COUNT(*)` would also work) and use it as the new column:

```
select *,  
  (
    select count(e2.Salary)
    from Employee e2
    where e2.Salary > e1.Salary
  ) as Head_count_of_higher_salary
from Employee e1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iEdtXRFcJqG2bWMANicjBm/0).

Answer (score 2):

You can also implement this type of query with a `LEFT JOIN` on the joined table having a higher salary than the first, and then counting the number of rows in the joined table:

```
SELECT e1.Id, e1.Name, e1.Salary, COUNT(e2.Id) AS Head_count_of_higher_salary
FROM Employee e1
LEFT JOIN Employee e2 ON e2.Salary > e1.Salary
GROUP BY e1.Id, e1.Name, e1.Salary
```

Output:

```
Id  Name    Salary  Head_count_of_higher_salary
1   toto    60000   2
2   tata    50000   4
3   kiki    90000   0
4   lily    70000   1
5   momo    60000   2
```

[Demo on SQLfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa40c6/5)

Answer (score 2):

If you are running MySQL 8.0: what you ask for is exactly what `rank()` does.

This would be as simple as:

```
select e.*, rank() over(order by salary desc) - 1 head_count_of_higher_salary
from employees e
```